# Failed to load Libmain.so The application will terminate

Tags: unity-game-engine

I am creating Il2cpp build app bundle (~aab file) after publishing it on play store getting "**Failed to load Libmain.so The application will terminate**" Error while opening app.

I rechecked aab file by WinRAR too still in its lib folder it doesn't have libmain.so file however ARMV7 Have libmain.so file but in ARM64 doesn't have libmain.so file.

I dont know why libmain.so file is not generating in aab file.

**Unity version :- 2019.3.0f6**

Comment: Do you have any solution for this issue? I have the same. Thanks

Comment: I check my custom gradle file and I written **"exclude ('/lib/arm64-v8a/' + '')"** This line which is preventing Libmain.so file to generate. So remove this line and it should work fine

Answer (score 1):

If are using custom gradle whiele building project make sure that everything is ok inside "packagingOptions" My mistake was I have included "exclude ('/lib/arm64-v8a/*' + '*')".